# XPath for numeric index order of element

Tags: xml, xpath, indexing

For an example of the following XML:

```
<media id="m12345">
    <medium view="top" mimeType="image/png">
        <description>Top</description>
        <url>https://www.source.org/123</url>
    </medium>
    <medium view="side" mimeType="image/png">
        <description>Side</description>
        <url>https://www.source.org/234</url>
    </medium>
    <medium view="bottom" mimeType="image/png">
        <description>Bottom</description>
        <url>https://www.source.org/345</url>
    </medium>
</media>
```

How would I return the value of "2" for the second medium element?

While parsing an XML file, I need to assign a unique value to the  elements combining @id from  and the numeric index of the  children.

So the first  element would be "m12345-1", the second would be -2, and so on.

Not sure if there is an index constant I could refer to or if counting preceding siblings was the best approach.

I was hoping that this would return "2", but it returns "1":

```
count(preceding-sibling:://media/medium[@view='side'])+1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `preceding-sibling:://media/medium[@view='side']` is a syntax error; it should not return anything. Whichever version of XPath you are using `axisname::` can be followed only by a NodeTest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this one:

```
count(//media/medium[@view='side']/preceding-sibling::medium) + 1
```

Just replace predicate `[@view="side"]` with `[@view="top"]` to get index `1` or with `[@view="bottom"]` to get `3`

Comment: While that's exactly what I need to happen, I couldn't get it to work. I am using

https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester#

to test. I do see my syntax issue now at least.

Comment: I'm not sure why your XPath tester has such behavior, but all 3 XPath testers that I usually use ([first](https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-xpath-tester.html), [second](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output), [third](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi)) returned correct result

Comment: Fair enough, works for me with your testers. Thanks!